# Concatenate DateTime string with Arabic String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to concatenate an Arabic string with a leading DateTime, I have tried in various way but the DateTime always ends up at the end of the string

```
var arabicText = "Jim قام بإعادة تعيين هذه المهمة إلى John";
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-AE");

string test1 = arabicText + " :" + dateTime.ToString();
string test2 = arabicText + " :" + dateTime.ToString(ci);
```

So when this is displayed it should show

> Jim قام بإعادة تعيين هذه المهمة إلى John :02/10/2012

but I always seem to end up with

> 02/10/2012: Jim قام بإعادة تعيين هذه المهمة إلى John

Any ideas would be apprecicated

Comment: Isn't arabic a right to left language?  So by adding it to the end, aren't you adding it to the left?

Comment: Yes Arabic is Right to Left, but if the parameters are swaped it still results in the same.

string test1 = dateTime.ToString() +": "+ arabicText;

Comment: I tried it out and ended up with what you're expecting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use with this code

```
var strArabic = "Jim قام بإعادة تعيين هذه المهمة إلى John";
var strEnglish = dateTime.ToString() ; 
var LRM = ((char)0x200E).ToString();  // This is a LRM
var result = strArabic  + LRM +  strEnglish ;
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1714591

Comment: it place a hidden string %200E

Answer (score 1):

Try using `string.Format`:

```
string test1 = string.Format("{0}:  {1}", arabicText, dateTime.ToString());
```

That should produce the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Arabic text goes from right to the left, so the version you end up with is correct.
If you really want it another way, why don't you just swap the arguments order?

Comment: Yes Arabic is Right to Left, but if the parameters are swaped it still results in the same. string test1 = dateTime.ToString() +": "+ arabicText;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the string.format() method ? Maybe it can solve your problem.